# How to create a moveable full size mask in css?

Tags: html, css, mask

I want to create an effect where there is a band of transparency that moves down an element. My first approach was to use a mask wrapper element that has a linear gradient from black to transparent to black and then animate the mask-position property to move it down the element.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qbea34sc/46/) the blue "2" is in the foreground and the red "1" is in the background.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/04/19/13/one-706897_1280.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.mask {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px red solid;

-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
      black 0%,
      transparent 20%,
      black 40%,
      black 100%);
      
-webkit-mask-position: 0% 50%;

/*   -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
      black 0%,
      transparent 50%,
      black 100%);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 20%;
  -webkit-mask-position: 0% 50%; */
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mask">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://media.gettyimages.com/id/182803848/photo/illustration-of-a-blue-number-2-in-3d.jpg?s=612x612&w=gi&k=20&c=GZvcBjuWwhLKFxhTUJX5lN4axZwXugVSTaJ_QPE0BA0=" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the 2 to be mostly visible except for a band of transparency through to the 1. You can see that mask-position does nothing if you modify it, im guessing since the mask is full size and it isnt allowed to exit its boundaries. Is there any way to allow a mask to overflow?

My second approach was to size down the mask with the mask-size property to allow it to be moveable within the element boundaries.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/04/19/13/one-706897_1280.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.mask {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px red solid;

/* -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
      black 0%,
      transparent 20%,
      black 40%,
      black 100%);
      
-webkit-mask-position: 0% 50%; */

-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
      black 0%,
      transparent 50%,
      black 100%);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 20%;
  -webkit-mask-position: 0% 50%;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mask">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://media.gettyimages.com/id/182803848/photo/illustration-of-a-blue-number-2-in-3d.jpg?s=612x612&w=gi&k=20&c=GZvcBjuWwhLKFxhTUJX5lN4axZwXugVSTaJ_QPE0BA0=" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qbea34sc/47/) you can see it works ok within the zone of the transparent gradient zone, but then because of the mask-repeat: no-repeat, makes the top image completely transparent above and below, ruining the effect. If i dont have the no-repeat, then there would be too many transparency bands.

How can I achieve this effect properly? Any other approach not involving masks would be ok too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a mask which is 'bigger' than the element it is working on, and it can be positioned so it 'overflows' - obviously it just doesn't have a visible effect outside the element.

This snippet makes the mask twice the height of its container with the top being black, a small transparent band and then more black. To give the blended look on the band it sets solid black for the first part, then black which will blend with the transparent, and similarly for the bottom part.

Obviously change the values to get exactly the height of band that you want and the amount of blending.

The snippet animates the mask position so you can see it works in different y positions.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/04/19/13/one-706897_1280.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.mask {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px red solid;
  /* -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
      black 0%,
      transparent 20%,
      black 40%,
      black 100%);
      
-webkit-mask-position: 0% 50%; */
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient( black 0 40%, black, transparent 50% 55%, black, black 60% 100%);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 200%;
  animation: move 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    -webkit-mask-position: 0% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-mask-position: 0% 0%;
  }
}


}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mask">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://media.gettyimages.com/id/182803848/photo/illustration-of-a-blue-number-2-in-3d.jpg?s=612x612&w=gi&k=20&c=GZvcBjuWwhLKFxhTUJX5lN4axZwXugVSTaJ_QPE0BA0=" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS - remember to include settings without the -webkit- too to accommodate Safari/FF.

Comment: So this was basically my first approach except with the mask sized up, can you explain to me why this works? why does position do nothing for a 100% size mask but moves it when the mask is 200% sized?